# How to automatically post an article onto my Facebook page

Tags: facebook, expressionengine, posting

I have a site built on an old version of expression engine. It's an article-based site that would auto post to its facebook page when an article was published. About a year ago this stopped working. How can I get this functionality back? The site is prosoundweb.com. Thanks.

Comment: How did it work before?

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php), it used to work a couple of years ago but Facebook has made it harder and harder to automate posting.